# Conversion of List of words (inside a dataframe) to a set of words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, I have a column with data as a list like [cell, protein, expression], I wanted to convert it as a set of words like cell, protein, expression, it should applies to entire column of the dataframe.  Please suggest the possible way to do it.

Comment: Are you looking to convert a lists inside a dataframe to strings? Converting the list `[cell, protein, expression]` to the string `cell, protein, expression`? if so just `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))`

Comment: Thank you, but its giving output as c, e, l, l, ,,  , p, r, o, t, e, i, n, ,,  , e, x, p, r, e, s, s, i, o, n. How get a complete word like, cell, protein, expression?

Comment: Can you show a sample dataframe? I cannot reproduce that issue with dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['cell', 'protein', 'expression']]})` and doing `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))`

Comment: Okay, I am sorry, Please have a look at the 1st sheet (Dataframe2) at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dHoVyEAi0SrY3QPgxRYXjl7CYkRvv0LVV_re38523ck/edit#gid=1021880412

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data['column_name'] = data['column_name'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `df['Final_Text']` is not a list but rather a string. try using `ast.literal_eval` first:

```
import ast
from io import StringIO

# your sample df

s = """
,Final_Text
0,"['study', 'response', 'cell']"
1,"['cell', 'protein', 'effect']"
2,"['cell', 'patient', 'expression']"
3,"['patient', 'cell', 'study']"
4,"['study', 'cell', 'activity']"
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# convert you string of a list of to an actual list
df['Final_Text'] = df['Final_Text'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# use a lambda expression with join to keep the text inside the list
df['Final_Text'] = df['Final_Text'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))

    Unnamed: 0      Final_Text
0      0            study, response, cell
1      1            cell, protein, effect
2      2            cell, patient, expression
3      3            patient, cell, study
4      4            study, cell, activity
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. If the data is format 0,"[study, response, cell] not as ("0,"['study', 'response', 'cell']"). Can you please suggest the alternative for code df['Final_Text'] = df['Final_Text'].apply(ast.literal_eval)?